# Use of *n in free format RPG

Tags: rpgle

So, I have got a job where fully free format RPG is used (even the D-Specs are in free).

I am confused about the use of "*N" in various declarations. Like in data structures, procedure prototypes etc.

My general understanding is that it is used as some sort of a placeholder when declarations without a name is defined.

Can someone help in understanding this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly right. *N indicates "no name". In free-form, you can't just omit the name completely the way you can in fixed-form, so *N is used as a place-holder. You use this for subfields, prototype-parameters, procedure interfaces, and unqualified data structures.

Answer (score 0):

[check out this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72961079/fully-free-rpg-data-structure)

RPG allows you overlay an array over the same memory location of other subfields in the same data struct. You declare nameless subfields in a data struct and give them initialize values.  Then overlay the array over those sub fields, making those sub fields items in the array.